# Grouping rows in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 2.4.0 and would like to know how to handle the following problem using Spark:

Each entry in the below data frames can have two different formats with their ids provided. What I would like to do is to group them together if two entries share the same id (either in format 1 or format 2) and assign a group id to each of the groups.

e.g.

Input data frame:

```
-------------------------------
Format1 Id    | Format2 Id    |
-------------------------------
Format1_1     |   Format2_1   |
Format1_2     |   Format2_1   |
Format1_3     |   Format2_1   |
Format1_4     |   Format2_2   |
```

Output data frame:

```
-------------------------------------------  
Format1 Id    | Format2 Id    | Group Id   |
-------------------------------------------
Format1_1     |   Format2_1   |  1         |
Format1_2     |   Format2_1   |  1         |
Format1_3     |   Format2_1   |  1         |
Format1_4     |   Format2_2   |  2         |
```

Since the first 3 entries share the same id in format 2, they are grouped together and assigned the same group id.

The last entry does not have any relationships with the precious three entries. It is treated as a single group.

I tried to use HashMap(String, Int) to map each format id to the corresponding group id, but since this HashMap is not distributed across nodes, the other worker nodes are not able to read the previously-inserted map values.

I am new to Spark and would like to know How I can implement this grouping problem in Spark?

Comment: If the rows are:
a|b
c|b
c|d
e|d
e|f
Then will they all belong to the same group?
a|b|1
c|b|1
c|d|1
e|d|1
e|f|1

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be treated as a graph problem where every id is a node and a pair of id's represents edges. So the ask is to find all the connected components and append the component id back to the original dataframe.

```
import org.graphframes._ //execute: spark-shell --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

case class Data(id1: Int, id2: Int) 
val data = Seq(Data(1,2), Data(1,3), Data(4,3), Data(4,5)) //sample dataset for testing
val df = data.toDF()

+---+---+
|id1|id2|
+---+---+
|  1|  2|
|  1|  3|
|  4|  3|
|  4|  5|
+---+---+

val nodes = df.select(concat(lit("id1_"), col("id1")).alias("id")).distinct.union(df.select(concat(lit("id2_"), col("id2")).alias("id")).distinct)
val edges = df.select(concat(lit("id1_"), col("id1")).alias("src"), concat(lit("id2_"), col("id2")).alias("dst"))
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("/tmp/checkpoints")
val g = GraphFrame(nodes, edges)
val comDf = g.connectedComponents.run()

val result = df.withColumn("id", concat(lit("id1_"), col("id1"))).join(comDf, Seq("id"), "left_outer").select("id1","id2","component")

+---+---+------------+
|id1|id2|   component|
+---+---+------------+
|  1|  2|154618822656|
|  1|  3|154618822656|
|  4|  3|154618822656|
|  4|  5|154618822656|
+---+---+------------+
```

Comment: @Eric If this answer worked please accept and upvote it :) Otherwise let me know what didn't work.

Comment: This solution works perfectly for my question. Thanks @Gsquare and sorry for the late accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dense_rank()` function.

```
scala> df.show()
+---------+---------+
|      _c0|      _c1|
+---------+---------+
|Format1_1|Format2_1|
|Format1_2|Format2_1|
|Format1_3|Format2_1|
|Format1_4|Format2_2|
+---------+---------+

// dataframe api
scala> df.withColumn("group_id",dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy('_c1))).show()

+---------+---------+--------+
|      _c0|      _c1|group_id|
+---------+---------+--------+
|Format1_1|Format2_1|       1|
|Format1_2|Format2_1|       1|
|Format1_3|Format2_1|       1|
|Format1_4|Format2_2|       2|
+---------+---------+--------+

// sql
scala> spark.sql("select df.*, dense_rank() over (order by _c1) as group_id from df").show()
```

Comment: This doesn't work when `_c0` has duplicates since the requirement is `the same id (either in format 1 or format 2)`